# SQL error in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have created a Form in MSAccess 2010 and when running I am getting following error :
**The select statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect**.

The name of my Database is Accessexp

Here is my code:

```any
   Private Sub SearchButton_Click()


    Dim dbs As Database
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim qdf As QueryDef
    Dim productName As String
    Dim lastNQuarters As String
    Dim strSql As String
    Dim columns As String
    Dim compstr As String
    Dim curstr As String
    Dim timestr As String
    Dim tablestr As String
    Dim sumstr As String
    Dim varItem As Variant
    Dim compcount As Integer
    Dim colcount As Integer
    Dim errorcount As Integer
    Dim Monthvalue As String


    Set dbs = CurrentDb()


    errorcount = 0
    colcount = 0
    lastNQuarters = Me!quarterbox.Value

    tablestr = ""
    timestr = Me!Monthbox.Value
    MsgBox (timestr)

    tablestr = "Q" & lastNQuarters


For Each varItem In Me!columnlist.ItemsSelected

     If Me!columnlist.ItemData(varItem) <> "---" Then
    columns = columns & "," & Chr(34) & Me!columnlist.ItemData(varItem) & Chr(34)
     colcount = colcount + 1
    End If
    Next varItem
    compcount = 0
    For Each varItem In Me!practicelist.ItemsSelected
       compstr = compstr & "," & Chr(34) & Me!practicelist.ItemData(varItem) & Chr(34)
         compcount = compcount + 1
    Next varItem

    If compcount = 0 Then MsgBox ("Warning: No Practice Selected"): errorcount = errorcount + 1
    If colcount = 0 Then MsgBox ("Warning: No Practice Selected"): errorcount = errorcount + 1

    If errorcount = 0 Then
          lastNQuarters = Me!quarterbox.Value


strSql = "Select  " & columns & ", " & tablestr & " from Accessexp where Accessexp.[Quarter] = " & tablestr & " and Accessexp.[Month] = " & timestr & ";"
            MsgBox (strSql)

            Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSql, dbOpenSnapshot)

          With dbs
          Set qdf = .CreateQueryDef("QueryOutput", strSql)
          DoCmd.OpenQuery "QueryOutput"
          .QueryDefs.Delete "QueryOutput"
          End With
          dbs.Close
           qdf.Close

        End If


    End Sub
```

My query is coming like this :

```sql
Select ,"Revenue Blended","Revenue Direct" Q4
from Accessexp
where Accessexp.[Quarter] = Q4 and Accessexp.[Month] = April;
```

Comment: Please remove the first comma `,` from your `Select` statement.

Comment: @nobodynoone : This statement is picking column value one by one from a List Box . In order to seperate them I have used           columns = columns & "," & Chr(34) & Me!columnlist.ItemData(varItem) & Chr(34)                                                          Is there any other way to seperate values with commas and not putting in begining ...

Comment: I'm not sure about MS Access 2010 but there must be something like in [php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). You should be checking whether your parameter is not null and then add comma based on that, so that you won't have additional characters, but instead will add them "on the fly"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this updated Code.

```
Private Sub SearchButton_Click()
    Dim dbs As Database, rs As Recordset
    Dim qdf As QueryDef
    Dim productName As String, lastNQuarters As String
    Dim strSql As String, columns As String, compstr As String
    Dim curstr As String, timestr As String, tablestr As String
    Dim sumstr As String, varItem As Variant
    Dim compcount As Integer, colcount As Integer, errorcount As Integer
    Dim Monthvalue As String

    Set dbs = CurrentDb()

    errorcount = 0
    colcount = 0
    lastNQuarters = Me!quarterbox.Value

    tablestr = ""
    timestr = Me!Monthbox.Value
    MsgBox timestr

    tablestr = "Q" & lastNQuarters

    For Each varItem In Me!columnlist.ItemsSelected
        If Me!columnlist.ItemData(varItem) <> "---" Then
            columns = columns & "[" & Me!columnlist.ItemData(varItem) & "],"
            colcount = colcount + 1
        End If
    Next 

    compcount = 0

    For Each varItem In Me!practicelist.ItemsSelected
        compstr = compstr & "[" & Me!practicelist.ItemData(varItem) & "],"
        compcount = compcount + 1
    Next

    If compcount = 0 Then 
        MsgBox ("Warning: No Practice Selected")
        errorcount = errorcount + 1
    Else
        compstr = Left(compstr, Len(compstr)-1)
    End If

    If colcount = 0 Then 
        MsgBox ("Warning: No Practice Selected")
        errorcount = errorcount + 1
    Else
        columns = Left(columns, Len(columns)-1)
    End If

    If errorcount = 0 Then
        lastNQuarters = Me!quarterbox.Value
        strSql = "SELECT  " & columns & " FROM Accessexp WHERE Accessexp.[Quarter] = '" & tablestr & "'" & _
                 " AND Accessexp.[Month] = '" & timestr & "';"
        MsgBox (strSql)
        Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSql, dbOpenSnapshot)

        With dbs                
            Set qdf = .CreateQueryDef("QueryOutput", strSql)
            DoCmd.OpenQuery "QueryOutput"
            '.QueryDefs.Delete "QueryOutput"
        End With
        dbs.Close
        qdf.Close
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: :It ran for the first time but next time onwards it is always giving this error : Run-time error '3012': Object 'QueryOutput' already exists. Pointing to this line : Set qdf = .CreateQueryDef("QueryOutput", strSql) –

Comment: Thanks I got the solution. Your code is working. Uncommented '.QueryDefs.Delete "QueryOutput"
and put it before Set qdf = .CreateQueryDef("QueryOutput", strSql)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other way to seperate values with commas and not putting in begining

After you've built your string with the leading comma just use

```vbs
columns = Mid(columns, 2)
```

to trim off the first character.

Other notes:

1. Wrap your column names in square brackets, not double quotes
2. String literals need to be enclosed in quotes.

Your resulting query string should look more like this:

```sql
Select [Revenue Blended],[Revenue Direct]
from Accessexp
where Accessexp.[Quarter] = 'Q4' and Accessexp.[Month] = 'April';
```